# How to cross reference in eqnarray

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

My cross references are not referencing the right equation labels. This is the code I am using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
SNR&=&10^{\frac{SNRdB}{10}}\\
\label{eq:snr}
&=&\frac{\sigma_s^2}{\sigma_N^2}\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{equation}
\sigma_N^2=\frac{\sigma_s^2}{SNR}
\label{eq:sn}
\end{equation}
Combining equations \ref{eq:snr} and \ref{eq:sn} we get
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have \label{eq:snr} in a line  with `\nonumber` put it in the line above

Comment: Put the `\label` before `\\\` (which really starts the second equation).

Comment: unrelated but avoid `eqnarray` and use `align` from `amsmath`

Comment: See also: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-eqnarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved `\\` to after the label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
SNR&=&10^{\frac{SNRdB}{10}}
\label{eq:snr}\\
&=&\frac{\sigma_s^2}{\sigma_N^2}\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{equation}
\sigma_N^2=\frac{\sigma_s^2}{SNR}
\label{eq:sn}
\end{equation}
Combining equations \ref{eq:snr} and \ref{eq:sn} we get
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Never use `eqnarray`. Ever.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:snr}
\begin{split}
\mathrm{SNR} &= 10^{\mathrm{SNR\,dB}/10} \\
&= \frac{\sigma_s^2}{\sigma_N^2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\sigma_N^2=\frac{\sigma_s^2}{\mathrm{SNR}}
\label{eq:sn}
\end{equation}
Combining equations \ref{eq:snr} and \ref{eq:sn} we get

\end{document}
```

[image]